# Commit/Save button in material design

Tags: material-design

I have a CMS system I'm implementing using Polymer/Material Design.

Due to a number of factors, changes made to the content cannot be applied immediately, the user must make a set of changes and then "Save" them to the backend.

The CMS currently looks like this:

[image]

I can't find any guidance in the Material Design guidelines on where to put such a button.

Is there any? Or should I just add a button at the bottom of the window as you would in any other CMS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from the material design guideline:

> Persistent footer buttons
>   If your app requires actions to be persistent and readily available to the user, consider using the floating action button.
>   Alternatively, consider persistent footer buttons, which are also easily accessible.

[image: Example of persistent footer buttons]

Comment: +1 I agree they should be placed at the bottom, and preferably always visible if the form can be saved at any time.